# LINQPad How to GroupBy Average of TimeSpan

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

How do you select a `GroupBy` Average on a `TimeSpan` in a `LINQPad` Query using `LinqToSQL` to Query an `SQL Server`?

I have tried converting everything to Ticks and everything else I can think of however I am not getting anywhere.

This is the `LINQ` Query, You probably only need to pay attention to the end however I am posting all of it just in case:

```
from so in TblServiceOrders 

where so.DateReceived!=null && 
      so.TimeReceived != null && 
      so.DateRequested!=null && 
      so.TimeRequested != null && 
      so.DateOpened != null && 
      so.TimeOpened != null


let DayReceived = so.DateReceived.Value.DayOfWeek
let DayRequested = so.DateRequested.Value.DayOfWeek
let DayOpened = so.DateOpened.Value.DayOfWeek

////Work out Business Hours in SLA
let SLADaysLapesed = ((so.DateRequested.Value.Day) - (so.DateReceived.Value.Day))

let SLAContainsWE = (DayReceived == DayOfWeek.Monday && SLADaysLapesed <= 4 ||
                     DayReceived == DayOfWeek.Tuesday && SLADaysLapesed <= 3 ||
                     DayReceived == DayOfWeek.Wednesday && SLADaysLapesed <= 2 ||
                     DayReceived == DayOfWeek.Thursday && SLADaysLapesed <= 1 ||
                     DayReceived == DayOfWeek.Friday && SLADaysLapesed <= 0 ? false : true )

let SLATotalDailyAH = (new TimeSpan(0, (930 * SLADaysLapesed), 0))

let TotalWEHours = (SLAContainsWE == true ? new TimeSpan(0,1020,0) : new TimeSpan(0,0,0))


let SLAHours =  (
                ((so.DateRequested.Value.AddHours(so.TimeRequested.Value.Hour)).AddMinutes(so.TimeRequested.Value.Minute)).Subtract
                ((so.DateReceived.Value.AddHours(so.TimeReceived.Value.Hour)).AddMinutes(so.TimeReceived.Value.Minute)).Subtract
                (SLATotalDailyAH).Subtract(TotalWEHours)
                )   


////Work out Business Hours in Passed before Job Opened
let OpenDaysLapesed = ((so.DateOpened.Value.Day) - (so.DateReceived.Value.Day))

let OpenContainsWE = (DayReceived == DayOfWeek.Monday && OpenDaysLapesed <= 4 ||
                     DayReceived == DayOfWeek.Tuesday && OpenDaysLapesed <= 3 ||
                     DayReceived == DayOfWeek.Wednesday && OpenDaysLapesed <= 2 ||
                     DayReceived == DayOfWeek.Thursday && OpenDaysLapesed <= 1 ||
                     DayReceived == DayOfWeek.Friday && OpenDaysLapesed <= 0 ? false : true )
let OpenTotalDailyAH = (new TimeSpan(0, (930 * OpenDaysLapesed), 0))

let TotalOpenWEHours = (OpenContainsWE == true ? new TimeSpan(0,1020,0) : new TimeSpan(0,0,0))


let OpenHours =  (
                 ((so.DateOpened.Value.AddHours(so.TimeOpened.Value.Hour)).AddMinutes(so.TimeOpened.Value.Minute)).Subtract
                 ((so.DateReceived.Value.AddHours(so.TimeReceived.Value.Hour)).AddMinutes(so.TimeReceived.Value.Minute)).Subtract
                 (OpenTotalDailyAH).Subtract(TotalOpenWEHours)
                 )  

group new {SLAHours, OpenHours} by "Total" into g



select new {
SLAHour = g.Average (x => x.SLAHours.Ticks),
OpenHour = g.Average (x => x.OpenHours.Ticks)
}
```

This is the `StackTrace` I get when trying to execute the Query:

```
StackTrace    at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.PostBindDotNetConverter.Visitor.VisitMethodCall(SqlMethodCall mc)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitExpression(SqlExpression exp)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.PostBindDotNetConverter.Visitor.VisitMethodCall(SqlMethodCall mc)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitExpression(SqlExpression exp)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.PostBindDotNetConverter.Visitor.VisitMethodCall(SqlMethodCall mc)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitExpression(SqlExpression exp)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.PostBindDotNetConverter.Visitor.VisitMember(SqlMember m)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitExpression(SqlExpression exp)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitUnaryOperator(SqlUnary uo)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.PostBindDotNetConverter.Visitor.VisitUnaryOperator(SqlUnary uo)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitExpression(SqlExpression exp)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitRow(SqlRow row)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSelectCore(SqlSelect select)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.PostBindDotNetConverter.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias a)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSource(SqlSource source)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSelectCore(SqlSelect select)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.PostBindDotNetConverter.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias a)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSource(SqlSource source)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSelectCore(SqlSelect select)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.PostBindDotNetConverter.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.PostBindDotNetConverter.Convert(SqlNode node, SqlFactory sql, ProviderMode providerMode)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(ResultShape resultShape, Type resultType, SqlNode node, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parentParameters, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
              at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
              at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
              at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
              at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) 
HelpLink null 
Source System.Data.Linq 
HResult -2146233067
```

As you can probably tell, I am trying to run this Query entirely within the `LinqToSQL` Query using `LINQPad4`

If I run the query and select all of "g" the output looks like this:

```
SLAHours      | OpenHours 
----------------------------
1.01:00:00    | 01:34:00 
27.02:32:00   | 125.06:06:00 
121.21:05:00  | 06:34:00 
29.17:36:00   | 1.04:44:00 
4.11:10:00    | 01:35:00 
4.19:26:00    | 1.03:26:00 
27.14:29:00   | 1.19:12:00 
04:01:00      | 00:14:00
```

==EDIT==
Added below example which is much smaller and seems to have a similar if not the same issue I am trying to overcome:

```
from so in TblServiceOrders 

where so.DateRequested!=null && 
      so.TimeRequested != null 

let SLAHours =  (so.DateRequested.Value.AddHours(so.TimeRequested.Value.Hour)).AddMinutes(so.TimeRequested.Value.Minute)

group new {open = SLAHours} by "Total" into g

select g.Average (x => x.open.Ticks)
```

Short Error: The member 'System.DateTime.Ticks' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: I think this question is too big. Can you reproduce your problem with smaller amount of code or just remove from this query stuff which is not related to your problem?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I've added another example, The error is a bit different but I think the issue is the same.

Comment: SQL server does not know Ticks => therefore you cannot use int in a Linq-2-sql query because it cannot be executed in SQL code. A solution might be to get a bigger results set from the database and continue with those results and Linq-to-object

Comment: @Pleun Is there any way to convert the .Ticks to an int and they run the Average on the int?

Comment: Once you have it in memory you can use Ticks and perform the average

Comment: @Pleun Alternatively is there a way to continue with the `Linq-to-object` in `LINQPad`?

Comment: Hi @Pleun, Thanks for the tips, I did end up completing this the way you suggested.
I'd still be interested if there is a better way to perform maths on a `TimeSpan`.